# When was the Millennium Falcon's sensory dish replaced?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, millennium-falcon

While watching the [trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=erLk59H86ww#t=61) again I noticed the sensory dish on the Millennium Falcon was replaced, I wonder if there is an  [answer](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Millennium_Falcon/Canon#cite_note-Set_to_Roll-2) from the expanded universe (books and alike) when it was replaced. Even more important, did Lando pay for it :)

Comment: They changed the dish so they could get the Disney channel.

Comment: truthfully since the movies are now in the hands of Disney any expanded universe explanations will not be valid. until after the movie is actually out, then Maybe some of the expanded stories will fit, but as of right now anything past return of the jedi is completely non-relevant to the new trilogy. (accepting that new cartoon)

Comment: I still would be interested what the current known answer is, even if the next movie should make it moot.

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it can not be answered without information not available until the future date

Comment: Even if I specifically ask for an expanded universe answer?

Comment: In the expanded universe, Han was constantly upgrading/replacing systems on the Falcon.

Comment: if you ask for an expanded universe answer you have to change the question, to after jedi did han replace the dish or something like that, not using the new movie as your reference.

Comment: You are completely right, done.

Comment: I don't really understand the "how" part of the question, can't think of many possible ways to fix the dish..

Comment: @Dagon313: Here's a few. 1)Alter the localised time around the dish to a past state where the dish was there. 2)Cast a mass illusion to make people see the dish while it's not there at all. 3)Get a Force user to keep tiny slivers of metal around there in the shape of a dish all the time. 4)Get a technician (or droid) to attach a new dish.

Comment: Awesome. So basically one possibility, unless you actually care if it was a technician or a droid.

Comment: Minor note. The new cartoon takes place between Episodes III and IV, not post ROTJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the upcoming Episode VII - including its trailer - is completely un-related to any existing EU material. Therefore it's impossible to answer this question within the context of the film or any upcoming official canon.

Within the existing "Legends" canon, however, it's safe to assume that the Falcon's dish was replaced within days after The Battle of Endor. The novel "Truce at Bakura" begins the day after the battle, and mentions that the Alliance fleet is being restored to working order. Han, of course, wants to ensure that the Falcon has top priority. In fact, while leaving for Bakura a few days into the novel, we have this passage (emphasis mine):

> Han Solo kept an eye on the Falcon's sensors as he swung the nimble
>   freighter aside. Too experienced to get caught in the battle group's
>   jump hyperwash, he couldn't resist watching until Luke's
>   carrier - imagine the kid commanding a carrier group - winked out.
>   Leia flinched.
>
> Now he was back where he belonged, on board the Falcon. ***Alliance
>   repair teams had wasted no time getting his beloved freighter back
>   into service after Lando rattled her around inside the second Death
>   Star*** (no hard feelings, Lando. It was for a good cause). He belonged
>   in this cockpit, with good old Chewie in the copilot's seat.

Throughout the 30-year period covered in "Legends" canon, the Millenium Falcon was upgraded and refitted multiple times, including at least one refit which restored it to near-mint condition (a condition which Han met with mixed emotion). It was also painted a non-reflective black color throughout much of the Yuuzhan Vong war, an update which rendered it nearly invisible to the naked eye & other biological sensor methods used by the Vong.